# remove options from select by values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array

```
del_array=["first option", "second option" ...]
```

And html

```
<select  id="delid">
    <option value="first option">first option</option>
    <option value="second option">second option</option>
...
```

And I want to delete all options with values from del_array

So I try

```
for(var i=0; i < del_array.length; i++) {
    jQuery('#delid option[value="del_array[i]"]').remove();
}
```

But it doesn't work

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost perfect. You need to change `'#delid option[value="del_array[i]"]'` into `'#delid option[value="' + del_array[i] + '"]'` because you want to get the `del_array` element values.

```js
var del_array = ["first option", "second option"];

for (var i = 0; i < del_array.length; i++) {
  jQuery('#delid option[value="' + del_array[i] + '"]').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="delid">
  <option value="first option">first option</option>
  <option value="second option">second option</option>
  <option value="foo">foo</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0; i < del_array.length; i++) {
        jQuery('#delid option[value="'+ del_array[i] +'"]').remove();
    }
```

please try the code above. You made mistake because the code execute del_array[i] as a string